# How to set up a chef server using vagrant?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, chef-infra

I want to setup a chef server using vagrant (virtual box).
Is there a predefined box or a vagrant file?

Thanks,
Liora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [vagrant-omnibus](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus) can install the latest (or any) version of Chef on whatever box you desire.

Comment: Does it install chef server? Tried it but it seems like the server is not there. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it installs the chef client.
You can then use Vagrant's built-in Chef provisioner (with an existing server, or in chef-solo mode), or use a tool like test-kitchen to move your cookbooks to the Vagrant machine

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to use Vagrant's build-in chef provisioner?

Comment: There is a whole section in the Vagrant documentation [here](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html)

Comment: Thanks Nils. I will check it up.